# \colorbox{color}{text} without increasing the height and width of the cell in a table

Tags: tables, color, boxes, dimensions

When using `\colorbox{color}{text}` to put background color for the `text` in a table, the `text` with background color seems to take more space and makes the respective cell higher and wider. Is there a way to use `\colorbox{color}{text}` in a table cell without affecting the dimension of the cell?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to set the value of `\fboxsep` to zero to remove the extra margin:

```
{\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\colorbox{<color>}{<text>}}
```

You don't need the outer braces if it is the whole cell, however then I would use the macros of the `colortbl` or `colortab` packages. The new `tabu` package also provides a lot of new features for tables, including a lot of different color features, but it might be an effort to change to this package.

---

You can also use the `adjustbox` package for this:

```
\adjustbox{cframe=<color>}{<text>}
```

which draws a tight frame as well.
It has also an extended syntax which allows to set the rule thickness, inner separation and outer margin:

```
\adjustbox{cframe=<color> <thickness> <inner sep> <outer margin>}{<text>}
```

The margin can be negative and if it is -(thickness+inner sep) the original size is kept, e.g.:

```
\adjustbox{cframe=blue {\fboxrule} {\fboxsep} {-\fboxrule-\fboxsep}}{<text>}
```

(The `{ }` around the macros are there to preserve the space behind them.)

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much. I was trying to use `colorbl` package for highlighting columns of table. However, I am using overlay/transition, and I am not sure how to do it. I may start another question to ask about it later.

Comment: + 1 `\adjustbox` is a perfect instrument, especially for those who are used to HTML formatting

Comment: @yegor256: Thanks, I indeed coded it because I missed the power of CSS.

Comment: I think it must be `-\fboxrule-\fboxsep` rather than `\fboxrule+\fboxsep`. I also tested this. Unfortunately I cannot edit it since changes must be at least 6 characters long.

Comment: @theV0ID: Yes, I originally stated that directly the line before but then made it false myself ;-) I fixed it now. Thanks for reporting it.