# colorbox inside texttt, keep alignment of text

Tags: spacing, color, typewriter

I would like to print some hex code and annotate it with colors.
I used `\texttt` and `\colorbox`, but the `\colorbox` adds half a space before and half a space after the text, thus the column alignment get's messed up.

```
\texttt{
AA E2 8E A2 E2 8E 9C 20 E2 8E B3 61 E2 81 B1 2D\\
62 E2 81 B1 E2 8E 9F \colorbox{red}{E2 8E A5 E2 8E AA 0A}20 20\\
32 48 E2 82 82 20 2B 20 4F E2 82 82 20 E2 87 8C\\
20 32 \colorbox{green}{48 E2 82 82 4F 2C 20}52 20 3D 20 34 2E 37\\
20 6B CE A9 2C 20 E2 8C 80 20 32 30 30 20 6D 6D\\
}
```

Here is the example:

[image: the colorbox starts at the beginning of the next word, but half a space is inserted afterwards]

Is it possible to have the columns correctly? I removed the space after the text, so the following columns are correctly aligned, but the text inside the colorbox is shifted in any case. Or before this is a XY problem, is there a method in latex how one would actually do this?

Comment: Maybe a dupe of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23681/colorboxcolortext-without-increasing-the-height-and-width-of-the-cell-in-a?

Comment: Whatever those colors mean, you better define a semantic command, that way you can program easily all. Taking David's answer, you can do `\newcommand*\hexcoloraux[2]{\hspace*{-\fboxsep}\textcolor{#1}{#2}\hspace*{-\fboxsep}}` and then `\newcommand*\hexpositive[1]{\hexcoloraux{green}{#1}}` and `\newcommand*\hexnegative[1]{\hexcoloraux{red}{#1}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `\fboxsep` padding around the box, in the answers in the question linked in comments there are suggestions for locally setting `\boxsep` to zero but here I suspect that you want the padding but to account for it so

```
\hspace*{-\fboxsep}\colorbox{red}{E2 8E A5 E2 8E AA 0A}\hspace*{-\fboxsep}
```

You might want to reduce `\fboxsep` a bit as well, or not, depending

```
\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}
```

for example (the default is 3pt)